# PySpark: create dataframe from random uniform disribution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe using random uniform distribution in Spark. I couldn't find anything on how to create a dataframe but when I read the documentation I found that `pyspark.mllib.random` has a `RandomRDDs` object which has a `uniformRDD` method which can create rdds from random uniform distribution.

But the problem is that it doesn't create two dimensional rdds. Is there a way I can create a two-dimensional rdd or (preferably) dataframe?

I can create a few rdds and use them to create a dataframe but the dataset I am using has many fields(100+) and creating 100s of rdds and then zipping them doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can generate uniform Vectors RDD and convert it to a DataFrame

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.mllib.random import RandomRDDs
data  = RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(sc, 10,10) \ # numpy.ndarray are not supported.
                  .map(lambda a : DenseVector(a)) \
                  .map(lambda a : (a,)) \ 
                  .toDF(['features'])

data.show()
# +--------------------+
# |            features|
# +--------------------+
# |[0.97051622217872...|
# |[0.39165143210012...|
# |[0.70067295066813...|
# |[0.59568555130484...|
# |[0.16572531686478...|
# |[0.92494190257048...|
# |[0.43691499080129...|
# |[0.28320336307013...|
# |[0.85420768678698...|
# |[0.65923297006740...|
# +--------------------+
```

For more info, you can always check to official documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=randomrdd#pyspark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD).

**EDIT :** (check comments)

If you want to have each value in a separated column, you don't need to convert your vectors into a DenseVector but into a list :

```
data  = RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(sc, 10,10).map(lambda a : a.tolist()).toDF()
data1.show()
# +-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+
# |                 _1|                 _2|                  _3|                 _4|                 _5|                 _6|                 _7|                  _8|                _9|                _10|
# +-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+
# |0.14585743784778926|  0.803498096310468| 0.31605227000909253| 0.8119612820220813|0.41447836235778723| 0.2676439013488928| 0.8524783652359866|  0.5701076199786781|0.6693708605568874| 0.8111256775283068|
# | 0.1827511073189425| 0.3350517687462683|  0.7400032940623857| 0.7869460532004358| 0.6448914199353433| 0.9805601228284964|0.20020913675524243|  0.7922294214683878|0.9374972404332362| 0.6765087842364208|
# |0.38625776221583874|0.04229839224493681|  0.7734933051852422| 0.0274813429089541|  0.311445753826302|0.25698473390480325| 0.9437646814604557|  0.4741747733429049| 0.290710728473321|  0.677912271088622|
# | 0.7896873370148003| 0.1858840420861243|  0.3197437373418126|0.10097010041540833|0.10289933172316801| 0.5449368374946228| 0.4030450125686461| 0.21948568405399982|0.8930079107298496| 0.7519921983394425|
# |  0.815811790931526| 0.3634760983908547| 0.42601575700182837|0.13606388717010864| 0.5861222009300258| 0.3340860113942531| 0.2557956812340677| 0.43528056172400853|0.3922245296661778| 0.8912435252335149|
# |0.30392495415210397| 0.7925870450504611|  0.9030779298622288| 0.8727793109267047| 0.8158542803828924| 0.7931830841520005| 0.6282396202128951|  0.1420886768888291|0.8614276809589785|0.17436606175314684|
# | 0.9382134044434042| 0.6749506191750686|0.015443852959660331|0.12038319457909019|  0.417781126294975|0.07393488977646023|0.31885174813644857|   0.728226037613587|0.9952269580720621|0.07007086773721505|
# |0.13783951066912703| 0.7119354308993141| 0.42197923155036043|0.29716042608097326| 0.9738408655296322| 0.9868052613269893| 0.6935287164137466|0.037473358201903895|0.3495081198619411| 0.8435628173797828|
# | 0.1587632683889939| 0.7360623327266481| 0.42321853435929413| 0.9677124294019807|   0.63138909800576|0.09938015379429832| 0.5399110874035429|  0.7668582384258967|0.7925729040215128| 0.1764801807830343|
# | 0.2588173671258266| 0.5196258205360417| 0.47988935453823345| 0.6699354533063644| 0.8233338127383266| 0.8249394954169588|0.32268906006759734|  0.2768177979947253|0.9951067081655113| 0.5263299321371093|
# +-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way I can have the values as columns instead of vectors? I need them as multiple columns because there is a matrix multiplication I need to perform using the dataframe resulting from this process.

Comment: I have added an answer to the question. Could you please take a look and advise on how I can improve the function?

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random dataframe with n rows and n columns you could use the following functions

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def generate_random_uniform_df(nrows, ncols, seed=1):
    df = spark.range(nrows).select(F.col("id"))
    df = df.select('*', *(F.rand(seed).alias("_"+str(target)) for target in range(ncols)))
    return df.drop("id")
```

and

```
def generate_random_normal_df(nrows, ncols, seed=1):
    df = spark.range(nrows).select(F.col("id"))
    df = df.select('*', *(F.randn(seed).alias("_"+str(target)) for target in range(ncols)))
    return df.drop("id")
```

for a standard normal distribution. However, the one suggested by eliasah

```
def generate_random_uniform_df(nrows, ncols):
    df  = RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(spark.sparkContext, nrows,ncols).map(lambda a : a.tolist()).toDF()
    return df
```

seems to be much faster.

Comment: Your function generate_random_normal_df seems to return columns that are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution ignores my own concern I mentioned in the question

> I can create a few rdds and use them to create a dataframe but the
>   dataset I am using has many fields(100+) and creating 100s of rdds and
>   then zipping them doesn't seem efficient.

```
def create_uniform_rdd(nrow, ncol, schema = None):
    random_rdd = RandomRDDs()
    rdds = []
    for each_col in range(ncol):
        rdds.append(random_rdd.uniformRDD(sc, nrow).collect())
    rdds = list(zip(*rdds))
    if schema is None:
        schema = StructType([StructField(str(i), FloatType(), False) for i in range(ncol)])
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdds, schema)
    return df
```

I had to do the `zip` bit because Spark dataframes are row oriented. I could have switched `ncol` with `nrow` in the `for` loop but since the number of rows I have are far larger than the number of columns

---

**EDIT**

Adding a time comparison of eliasah's method and my method

```
def create_uniform_rdd_vector(nrow, ncol, schema = None):
    data  = RandomRDDs.uniformVectorRDD(sc, nrow,ncol).map(lambda a : a.tolist()).toDF()
    return data

def create_uniform_rdd(nrow, ncol, schema = None):
    random_rdd = RandomRDDs()
    rdds = []
    for each_col in range(ncol):
        rdds.append(random_rdd.uniformRDD(sc, nrow).collect())
    rdds = list(zip(*rdds))
    if schema is None:
        schema = StructType([StructField(str(i), FloatType(), False) for i in range(ncol)])
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdds, schema)
    return df

def timer_func(func, niter = 10):
    tic = time()
    for i in range(1,niter+1):
        nrow = i*1000
        ncol = i*10
        _ = func(nrow, ncol, schema = None)
    tac = time()
    return tac - tic

niter = 5
create_uniform_rdd_time = timer_func(create_uniform_rdd, niter) # 4.27 secs
create_uniform_rdd_vector_time = timer_func(create_uniform_rdd_vector, niter) # 1.31 secs
```

Comment: This solution won't scale good. I have updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: @eliasah, indeed. Added a time comparison

Comment: Thanks for the mini benchmark ! It should get worst on bigger scale.